# Replacing the V in MVC with ReactJS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

If i use ReactJS as my front end instead of JSPs or say Thymeleaf or anyother templating engine out there in MVC architecture.
Will my application still be inside the rules of an MVC application?
Will it still be called a MVC app?

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if i am wrong. MVC stands for Model-View-Controller and i guess it refers to architecture of your app not type of it. So as long as your application renders based on your models from database it should be in boundaries of MVC arch.

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what my concern is; MVC's entire pillar is based on M and the C.